# Ho to select one spreadsheet after another in LibreOffice?

Tags: select, spreadsheet, libreoffice

How to select spreadsheets one after another in Libre Office to perform some action in them?

In excel vba the following code worked, but it does not work in LibreOffice

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws in wb.Worksheets

        'Do something here
    End if
Next
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all get the `oSheets` object (which is what is called `Worksheets` in Excel) of `ThisComponent` (which is what is called `ActiveWorkbook` in Excel)

```
Sub sheetProcessing()
Dim oSheets As Variant, oSheet As Variant
Dim i As Long
' By Sheet index
    oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
    For i = 0 To oSheets.getCount() - 1
        oSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(i)
        Print oSheet.getName() & " - " & oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0).getString()
    Next i
' Or by Element Names
Dim oElementNames As Variant
    oElementNames = oSheets.getElementNames()
    For i = LBound(oElementNames) To UBound(oElementNames)
        oSheet = oSheets.getByName(oElementNames(i))
        Print oSheet.getName() & " - " & oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0).getString()
    Next i
' Or easiest
    For Each oSheet In oSheets
        Print oSheet.getName() & " - " & oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0).getString()
    Next oSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortonatelly the above mentioned solution does not work in LibreOffice

Comment: @AgnieszkaLiszka You will not believe it, but before publishing, I tested this code in LibreOffice Calc. There are three different variants for processing the `Sheets` object, which are obtained using the [**.getSheets()**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XSpreadsheetDocument.html#getSheets) method from the `ThisComponent`. Perhaps you didn't have any spreadsheet open that Basic could recognize as the `ThisComponent`?

Comment: I have just found out why it does not work - I am usung Google Apps Script - not Libre Office. Does anyone know how to write this code in  Google Apps Script so that it worked?

Comment: @AgnieszkaLiszka Oh, it's very similar - the method you want is also called `.getSheets()`. See two good use cases [**here**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134812/list-all-sheet-names-google-sheets).